# Few test fail in protractor with 199 error

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I am very new to protractor, I am fixing non-reg written by x-team members, the issue Im facing is all the test scripts work perfectly, except 3 of them, I am unable to find out how to start investigating the issue or what the issue could be.

the 199 error I have seen here is mostly associated with browser/ chrome driver issues, but hundreds of the other tests in the same folder work absolutely fine and these scripts get skip execution, hence they show result as fail.

I tried checking if there could be any issue in the script, but the script appears fine.

here is the error I get, when this particular script is run:

```
> mui-qa@1.0.0 prepro-run C:\mui_2jan
> node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc || echo done

> mui-qa@1.0.0 pro-run C:\mui_2jan
> node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor jsTranspiledFiles/config.js

spcefile: { browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions:
   { args:
      [ '--start-maximized',
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--allow-file-access',
        '--allow-insecure-localhost',
        '--allow-running-insecure-content',
        '--enable-automation' ] },
  specs: [] }
[23:57:32] W/launcher - You have specified both capabilities and multiCapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored
[23:57:32] E/launcher - Spec patterns did not match any files.
[23:57:32] E/launcher - Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.
    at Runner.run (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:322:19)
    at TaskRunner.run (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\protractor\built\taskRunner.js:110:27)
    at createNextTaskRunner (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:235:28)
    at helper.runFilenameOrFn_.then.then.then (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:260:13)
    at _fulfilled (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\mui_2jan\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
[23:57:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 199
npm ERR! mui-qa@1.0.0 pro-run: `node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor jsTranspiledFiles/config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 199
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mui-qa@1.0.0 pro-run script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rbegum\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-05T18_27_32_296Z-debug.log
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your config file, I see multiple problems:

`specs: []` && `Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.` no specs specified. Maybe because it's specified in a wrong place

what is `spcefile`?

`You have specified both capabilities and multiCapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored` error. I would not recommend using `multiCapabilities` until you become comfortable with protractor

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your **specs list specs: [] is empty**. you must provide the specs files which you want to execute in your script. the protractor.conf files do not know which file to execute.

Basically, in layman's terms, the flow is you write your specs file let's say spec1.ts, spec2.ts, and so on.

Then you need to mention those files in your protractor.conf files.

Details can be found https://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview